# Cache not outputting chunks of content

Tags: cache

I have a simple caching setup on this site. I have a layout template that extends it has this:

```
{% block content %}
    {% cache %}
      <p>my content</p>
    {% endcache %}
{% endblock %}
```

And i have `'enableTemplateCaching' => true` set to on for the production site in my config.

Since upgrading Craft from quite a old version to the latest as of a few weeks ago, the cache seems to have gone a bit haywire.

If i clear the cache and then load the pages, all seems well, but then if i edit a template for example, elements on some pages don't output.

One example is a map block, if i edit the latitude for the js in that block and then save that template, it doesn't output the js from that block which btw uses `{% includeJs myJs %}`. Other template elements seem to be missing also in other places.

This all worked before, but doesn't now, no idea why!

Comment: The behavior sounds like you're running into a fatal PHP errors.  Anything in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` or your web server's error logs? Have any stalled tasks?

Comment: Hey @BradBell, no, no stale tasks ands no mention of any php errors in the logs either. It's very odd!

Comment: Any other types of caching going on? Varnish, Fastly, opCache, APC, etc.?

Comment: @BradBell Nope, no caching. I'm going to go through and remove what add-ons i can, if it's that that is causing the issue. I have removed all caching tags which has removed the buggy output but would like to go back and cache expensive partials on this one.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track.  Strip everything down to the barebones and start adding things back in one at a time until the issue re-appears.